# "Roll Up Summary" trigger to summarize Opportunity Amount to Custom Object

Tags: apex

I have a custom object "Opportunity Project", and Opportunity has a lookup to the custom object. Each "Opportunity Project" could have a handful of Opportunities related to it. Need a basic trigger that grabs the total of the Opportunity Amounts and updates a currency field on the Opportunity Project record. (Cannot make Opportunity a Child under a custom object)

Comment: Also look up Declarative Lookup Rollup Summaries by Andrew Fawcett. You don't have to write this stuff yourself.

Comment: and while you are at it - vote up this idea: https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000BrqsAAC